# Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the windows hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I meet a strange problem: I made 2 view controllers for wich I can switch the view with code:

```
var currentViewController:UIViewController=UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!

func showController()
{
    let ViewControllernew1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController2")

    currentViewController.present(ViewControllernew1, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

My app open correctly to the first view controller, then, when I click on the button created on a sprite kit scene, I can switch the view to my new view controller successfully (I get my second scene successfully showed) but then, I can not change anymore my view controller after this switch. If I click again on the button, I get this message:

Attempt to present  on Test_Vuforia.GameViewController: 0x12f549610 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Do you know what is the problem ? I understand I'm in the root position so that I can not change anymore my view controller after having switched it, but how to change that ?

Thanks !

Edit:

My code is used inside a SKScene and not from a UIVewController and I get this error when I use the suffix self. : Value of type View (SKScene) has no member 'present'.

I'm creating an augmented reality game with Vuforia and I need to switch AR view with SKScene.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Issue

Current viewController is not the `rootViewController` from `UIApplication`. So you should find the current viewController which is visible and then present it from there.

### Solution

Simply find the topViewController on your `UIApplication Stack`, and from there present your controller.

```
let newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController2")
UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This extension of `UIApplication` comes in handy for your case

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(base: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: presented)
        }
        return base
    }
}
```

References: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/snikch/3661188)

Comment: Your solution is working, thanks ! The only problem is my iPad Air 2 become very very slow (nearly freezing) after 3 cycles of presentation of ViewController.The RAM usage grow to 90 MB wich is not so much for an Ipad Air 2, do you know why this happens ? Maybe it's necessary to clean and remove the old already viewed viewcontrollers ?

Comment: Well it depends on what you are doing there. If you don't need the presentedControllers after a while, you can change the `rootViewController` to the one that you need to present.

Answer (score 4):

Calling function in **viewDidAppear** helps in my case. Solution for **Swift 3**:

**In your Main Controller:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    showTutorialModally()
}

func showTutorialModally() {
    let tutorialViewController = TutorialViewController()
    tutorialViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(tutorialViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**In your Tutorial Controller:**

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
view.isOpaque = false
```

Answer (score 3):

Xcode error significance for roughly: this view is not in the Window of the view hierarchy.

What I don't think the above answer questions, but maybe you might have wondered why this would happen.

But I find that you are the reasons for this problem is likely to be in the ViewController life cycle at ViewDidLoading switch view Code execution inside.

Reason is probably that, when the ViewController implementation allco init during initialization, it will be executed asynchronously viewWillLoad - > viewDidLoad... -- -- -- -- > viewDidApper. Then may be in code execution to the viewDidLoad. The ViewController may not assign values to the Window. The rootViewController. So we directly use [self presentViewController:] will appear this error.

It is recommended that you move the code of the switch to ViewDidApper.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the extension below to retrieve the next available controller in the stack.

***Swift 3***

```
extension UIResponder {
    func next<T: UIResponder>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return next as? T ?? next?.next(type)
    }
}
```

***Swift 2.3***

```
extension UIResponder {
    func nextResponder<T: UIResponder>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return nextResponder() as? T ?? nextResponder()?.nextResponder(type)
    }
}
```

Inside your `SKScene`, `view?.next(UIViewController.self)` gives you the next available `UIViewController` in the hierarchy.

Add this extension to a group in your project called Categories, if this group does not exist already create it, then create a new file called `UIResponder+NextOfType.swift` and paste the extension.

Comment: I get an error "cannot call value of non-function type 'UIResponder' when I use: next(UIViewController.self)?.present(ViewControllernew1, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Are you using swift 3?

Comment: Yes with XCode 8 and Sierra

Comment: here is my code: let newViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController3")
        next(UIViewController.self)?.present(newViewController , animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Okay, this will work if you update the extension with the one in my updated answer

Comment: Yes, the code is compilling fine without error but nothing happens when I press the button, no view change...

Comment: Since you're inside an `SKScene`, you will need to use `view?.next(UIViewController.self)`

Comment: It's working ! Thanks very much for your help, I get the same problem, after 2 cycles of changing view, my iPad Air 2 become very slow and freezes (nothing special done here, I just switch simple SKScene)

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
func showController()
{
    let ViewControllernew1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController2")

    vc.present(ViewControllernew1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Maybe the issue is with the currentViewController.

Comment: The problem is I use this code in a SKScene and self.present(ViewControllernew1, animated: true, completion: nil) is not working, I get this error: Value of type View (SKScene) has no member 'present'.

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably your `rootViewController` is not the current `ViewController`. Either you presented or pushed a new UIViewController on top of it.
2. The `viewController's` view is not in the
   window's view hierarchy at the point that it has been loaded (when
   the `viewDidLoad` message is sent), but it is in the window
   hierarchy after it has been presented (when the `viewDidAppear`:
   message is sent). *if you calling `showController` method from
   `viewDidLoad` just call it from `viewDidAppear` method*

Do something like:

```
 let vc: UIViewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController2"))!
 self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

```
 // OR
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```