# Swift How to present view in root navigation after dismiss modal

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to make ViewController present after Modal dismiss

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let chatRoomVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatRoomVCId") as! ChatRoomVC
chatRoomVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
chatRoomVC.passValue = passValue

self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    self.present(chatRoomVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

But it will return "whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" maybe it's present a view after the controller dismissed

[image: The flow I suppose]

Comment: you should have to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304405/attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-windows-hierarchy/40304652#40304652.

Comment: The navigation bar will be disappeared if I present that view in modal.

Comment: Thanks @HimaliShah, but it's not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the `self` in `self.present`, what you are doing, is basically tell the vc that you are dismissing to present a new vc, thats wrong way to do, the correct way is tell it's PARENT vc to present a new vc, by using delegate/unwind to call the parent vc to present new vc

Comment: I used unwind for action. But I got another error "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" even I disabled the animation of unwind segue. I call performSegue in the unwind IBAction.

Comment: Did you call unwind in your `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:`?

Comment: I just call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToVC", sender: self.passValue)`. It's work without using dismiss function. If I add it into dismiss completion, it will not effect

Comment: Ah yes, this is because it will handle the dismissing action also, in your unwind method, put the performSegue in `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { ... }` to delay it a little bit then the warning will be gone

Answer (score 0):

You are using self. It means you are dismissing the current view controller. It should be the parent view controller who will present a new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

When present from "Controller_A" to "Controller_B"-> present it like given below

--- View Controller A ---

```
self.navigationController?.present(Controller_B, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When you want to dismiss "Controller_B" and present "Controller_C" using Navigation controller

--- View Controller B ---

```
let presenController : UINavigationController = self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController

presentingController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
  presenController.pushViewController(Controller_C, animated: true)
})
```