# swift3 present from appdelegate error : Warning: Attemp to present ~ whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift3, appdelegate

swift3, xcode8 ios

I'm creating an app that calls a button on a widget to show a specific page in App

For example, an app consists of viewA and viewB, and the first view is viewA
I'm trying to show viewB when I press a button in a widget.

## Source

---

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let DetailView: Detail_Update_View = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail_Update_View") as! Detail_Update_View

let nav2 = UINavigationController.init (rootViewController: DetailView)
self.window?.rootViewController? .present (nav2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

This is called from the func `open url` in AppDelegate.

When you click on a button in the widget, viewB is called initially.
Open the widget again and press the button
The page will be called but the information will not change and the following error will be displayed

## errorMessage

---

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x101a1b600> on <SWRevealViewController: 0x101820c00> whose view is not the window hierarchy!
```

---

If you make a first call to the widget, close the viewB screen (go to viewA) and click the button in the widget to get it working.

please help me..

Comment: then you need to set initial viewcontroller in storyboard .

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40304837/3901620

Comment: @KKRocks thank you for reply. it's looks like work! but.. If I try 3 times, I have to go back to each page by pressing the back button 3 times. Is there any way to go to viewA at once?

Comment: put code for how to back from controller ?

Comment: @KKRocks actually, there are two way.. one of them is navigationController.popViewController and other thins is dismiss

Comment: which one you used ?

Comment: @KKRocks both of them. cause If I use only the latter, I will not go back if I open it in the widget. If I use only the front, I will not go back if I opened it in viewA.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let DetailView: Detail_Update_View = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail_Update_View") as! Detail_Update_View

  let nav2 = UINavigationController.init (rootViewController: DetailView)
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

  appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present (nav2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: thank you for answer. but it's same... first of your answer was work well. but have one problem that can't go back viewA

Comment: If you make navigation controler for push view controller than  only you can  pop it is preset view controller you can only dismiss this

Comment: sorry.. i can't understand what you mean... what should i do?

Comment: if you want to back than you should make navigation push view controller other wise above code presenview controller are using  you can only dismiss.