# Error unwrapping View Controller when called through Appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, appdelegate

So i'm trying to present a passwordVC over the current vc when an app reaches the foreground. Current, on the passcodeVC (the VC i'm trying to present on top) has this function:

```
func present() {
        print("calling present")
        if let passcodeVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IdlePasscodeVC") {
        passcodeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(passcodeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("there was an error unwrapping")
        }
    }
```

I call that through the AppDelegate when the app reaches foreground with this code:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) { 
        print("app entered foreground")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let passcodeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LockVC") as?  IdlePasscodeViewController{
        passcodeVC.present()
    }
    }
```

Fixed one issue; but now i'm getting an error "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Is there a way to fix this? or is there a better method someone can show me (i've read notification center and a listener is possible, but i have no clue where to begin).

**looking to have the passcode VC present itself on top of the last open screen, so that when the passcode is correct, it can dismiss itself**

A possible alternative method would be helpful.

EDIT : is it possible to use this solution?

[Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the windows hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304405/attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-windows-hierarchy)

Comment: I think you need instanciate this viewController as you do before with storyboard

Comment: where do i do that? in the present() function?

Comment: IdlePasscodeViewController is the type of the controller you need be presented, but what is the class of the viewController that have the `present()` method?

Comment: @ReinierMelian it's a UIViewController; could you elaborate, i'm kind of green.

Comment: when you say -> let vc = IdlePasscodeViewController() and then vc.present() This "vc" object is a new object and it doesn't have storyboard var initialized (unless it is computed property or you have handled it in someway.) => So your "storyboard?" is nil.

Comment: @AmreshKumar I see, i'm not sure how to go about fixing it though; i'm rather new. I don't suppose you could give me a code example of how to fix this? I've been stuck on this for hours and it would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: I need the Class name of the ViewController that have the method present() to help you

Comment: @ReinierMelian class IdlePasscodeViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate     like that?

Comment: instead of storyboard?.instantitate.... say => UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiate... I'm assuming your storyboard name is Main.storyboard

Comment: yes, but your IdlePasscodeViewController is presenting itself as modal?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I'm trying to use the app delegate foreground method to call the method on my passcode VC (it's a lock screen i've created) to put itself over the current screen with a method on it's own VC. So yes, i'm trying to get it to present itself. That way, when the code is correct, i can just dismiss it and the screen that was open be under it.

Comment: @BitBeast check my answer then, I think is what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this i think that can help you in some way

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) { 
        print("app entered foreground")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        if let passcodeVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IdlePasscodeVC") as?  IdlePasscodeViewController{
        passcodeVC.present()
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i get an error saying "use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard"'

Comment: @BitBeast check again, I assume that your main storyboard is called Main

Comment: yes, i edited the identifier to make it correct, but now i'm getting an error "Warning: Attempt to present <EmoteNote.IdlePasscodeViewController: 0x101c2fe20> on <EmoteNote.IdlePasscodeViewController: 0x101c238c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: sure, is what iam trying to say, you need to add your VC to your Window

Comment: @BitBeast you have this viewController in the navigation stack before you go to background?

Comment: @ReinerMelian Do you know of any better solutions to accomplish what i'm trying to do? all i want to do is have the passcode screen present every time the app becomes inactive or goes background. I've been trying to get this to work for almost 2 days and i'm reaching the limit of my novice understanding. The initial view controller is a tabbar controller btw.

Comment: @BitBeast Let me think about it, i will post something soon

Comment: i just made the lock the initial vc and instantiate it every time it goes background; thanks for the help.

Comment: @BitBeast Sorry I was very busy, a lot of work, but I think you can do it in you base view controller and implementing a method for enter in foreground showing your lock viewController, I don't know if you can understand me